# Can I use a vector drawable the same way I used a 9 patch?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I've been playing a lot with the 9-patch, they are a huge relief when it comes to making a nice background for a button, a form, etc.

As the vector drawables are now available with the support library for a large range of Android versions, I am looking forward to use the vector drawables the same way I used 9-patch images.
Sadly, I did not come across any possibility to set content padding and patches...

Has anyone managed to achieve this 9-patch/svg mix ?

Answer (score 11):

This is a bit awkward but it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <item
        android:left="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners_plus_tail"
        android:right="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:bottom="@dimen/speech_bubble_spacing"
        tools:width="50dp"
        tools:height="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/speech_bubble_user"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:bottom="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners_plus_tail"
        android:left="@dimen/speech_bubble_spacing"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/speech_bubble_user"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:bottom="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners_plus_tail"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/speech_bubble_user"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:height="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:bottom="@dimen/speech_bubble_spacing"
        android:gravity="bottom|right">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
            android:height="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
            android:viewportWidth="10.0"
            android:viewportHeight="10.0">
            <path
                android:pathData="M0,10 A10,10 0 0,0 10,0 L0,0 Z"
                android:fillColor="@color/speech_bubble_user"/>
        </vector>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:height="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:gravity="top|right">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
            android:height="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
            android:viewportWidth="10.0"
            android:viewportHeight="10.0">
            <path
                android:pathData="M10,10 A10,10 0 0,0 0,0 L0,10 Z"
                android:fillColor="@color/speech_bubble_user"/>
        </vector>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:height="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
        android:left="@dimen/speech_bubble_spacing"
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
            android:height="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners"
            android:viewportWidth="10.0"
            android:viewportHeight="10.0">
            <path
                android:pathData="M10,0 A10,10 0 0,0 0,10 L10,10 Z"
                android:fillColor="@color/speech_bubble_user"/>
        </vector>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners_plus_tail"
        android:height="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners_plus_tail"
        android:gravity="bottom|left">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners_plus_tail"
            android:height="@dimen/speech_bubble_corners_plus_tail"
            android:viewportWidth="150.0"
            android:viewportHeight="150.0">
            <path
                android:pathData="M150,100 L150,0 L50,0 C50,11.9054549 52.5180742,22.2130322 55.2200144,32.2289993 C59.25,47.1679688 65.7054859,60.8615415 68.15625,65.5820312 C55.2200144,107.207031 41.7460938,127.800781 0,151 C61.5311854,147.539062 101.691406,129.675781 124.615295,97.6602593 C132.823321,99.8389881 141.106342,100 150,100 Z"
                android:fillColor="@color/speech_bubble_user"/>
        </vector>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I was using the following in `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="speech_bubble_corners">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="speech_bubble_corners_plus_tail">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="speech_bubble_spacing">5dp</dimen>
```

Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image: Two speech bubbles]

It would be nicer if the path could take variable nine-patch sections. It seems like it shouldn't be theoretically hard. Each section could have something like a `+x` or `+y` as options to add into the pathData. I guess it might be possible to calculate this in code and programatically create the appropriate vectors as they were needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can not apply a 9-patch behaviour to a vector drawable in specific zone. 9-patch are designed for [bitmap](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) and a bitmap is just a grid of pixels stored in a `int [x][y]`. For a resizable bitmap, the 9patch behaviour says "hey the column 12 (a 9patched one) can be duplicated n times in parallel
" then, the image  is stretched and **no longer proportional**.

While a vector drawable is *only* a static drawing path definition. The result will be always rescaled and **proportional** to its original path because the path do not change dynamically.

Comment: so a 9 patch is not equivelant to a a vector then ? right ?  i would still use 9-patch when i have a certain part of the image which should not stretch or be scaled right ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler `layer-list` drawable with just two elements, which produces the same output as in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50176317/1037294):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/bubble_bottom_shift"
        android:left="@dimen/bubble_left_shift"
        android:gravity="fill">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="@dimen/tail_width"
        android:height="@dimen/tail_height"
        android:gravity="bottom|left">
        <vector
            android:width="@dimen/tail_width"
            android:height="@dimen/tail_height"
            android:viewportWidth="16.0"
            android:viewportHeight="16.0">
            <path
                android:fillColor="#fff"
                android:pathData="YOUR TAIL PATH DATA HERE" />
        </vector>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```